# How do I fix this: fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an issue adding a result to my database. Here is my code for linking.

```
$startingunix = strtotime($dates . " " . $startingtime); //
$endingunix = strtotime($dates . " " . $endingtime);

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "x";
$password = "x";
$dbname = "josfei6_ge";


// Create connection
$connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,      $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$connection) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");

global $mysqli;

$sql="SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `description` = '$desc' ORDER BY    starttime;";

$records=mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

$numberofevents = 0;

$okay = 0;




while($eventnow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){}
```

I get the error when I try to add data to the database:

```
$dbconnection->query($sql);
```

It gives me an error of:
    `fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object`

Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Should be $connection->query($sql);

Comment: You've got `$connection`, `$dbconnection` and also `$mysqli`...  What gives?

Comment: @AbraCadaver, the OP already told you what gives - he said it gives a fatal error ;)

Comment: Thanks everyone! Fixed it!

Comment: dang I can't downvote this. The kid's in high school

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. Using string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). Rule of thumb: **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.